# Logging SQL in Grails 3.3.1 unit tests

Tags: testing, grails, logging

When running unit tests in Grails 3.3.1, how can I view the SQL logging? I can view the SQL logging when running the application normally using the settings below.

application.yml

```
    hibernate:
        format_sql: true


    test:
        dataSource:
              logSql: true
    development:
        dataSource:
              logSql: true
```

logback.groovy

```
logger 'org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder', TRACE, ['STDOUT']
logger 'org.hibernate.SQL', TRACE, ['STDOUT']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use HibernateSpec instead of just Specification on the unit tests.  Then using the above SQL logging will work.

```
class MyServiceSpec extends HibernateSpec implements ServiceUnitTest<MyService>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not hit database when running unit-tests. All external interactions like DB etc should be mocked.

Integration and functional tests are more suitable to verify what queries are sent to DB.

See the [documentation](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/testing.html)

Comment: I do use stub and mock when necessary, but I am testing a service which performs database interactions.  In the unit tests, the database interactions are being performed using the GORM DomainUnitTest class for testing which uses the in-memory database.  For complicated search criteria it is not working correctly for the tests.  This is similar to the issue GRAILS 8841 and GRAILS 10507, so I was curious to see what was actually being executed.

Comment: @Tabbycat Are you sure that any SQL is executed there and the result is not simply stored in ConcurrentHashMap or sort of?

Comment: Anton - I thought it used SQL, but you are probably correct.  I did find that the HibernateSpec uses SQL.